# Why does this Python list of dictionary only have the keys of the dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, python-import

I wrote a module, which is serving as a config file:

```
users = list(
             dict(
                  username="x",
                  password="y"
                  )
             )
```

However, when I inspect the imported contents of the list, it contains the keys of the dictionary, not a dictionary entry:

```
>>> import user as userdata
import user as userdata
>>> userdata.users
userdata.users
['username', 'password']
>>>
```

Comment: Note that `list(x)` is not the same thing as `[x]`.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, and should not be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the list from a dictionary. The list constructor will iterate over the dict, which just gives the keys.

If you want a list that contains the dict as one element, you can use:

```
[dict(username='test')]
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not making a list of dicts, you are making a list of dictionary keys from the dictionary, `list(dict(...))` returns a list of keys:

```
>>> d = dict(username="x", password="y")
>>> list(d)
['username', 'password']
```

Probably you want to define `users` this way:

```
users = [dict(username="x", password="y")]
```

or

```
users = [{'username': 'x', 'password': 'y'}]
```

Comment: No, probably he wants `[{'username': 'x', 'password': 'y'}]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 users = [dict(username="x",password="y")]
 print users
```

if you want to have array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you call `list` on a dictionary, it makes a new list of only your keys, which is the same as using the method call of `yourdictionary.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why would you use `dict( )` when you can simply use `{ }`..

You know the dictionary functions? If not I'd recommend you to try the `dir()` function.

There are some functions in there that you can use:

dictionary.`keys()`, returns a list of all the keys in the dictionary.

dictionary.`values()`, returns a list of all the values in the dictionary.

dictionary.`items()`, returns a list which in each cell there are 2 'variables', [0]=key, [1]=value

Example:

```
d = { "First":1, "Second":2 }
d.keys()
>> [ "First", "Second" ]
d.values()
>> [ 1, 2 ]
d.items()
>> [ ("First", 1), ("Second", 2) ]
```